# Deleting Dynamics365 systemuser via API

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Does anyone know if there is a way to delete Dynamics365 systemuser via API?

If I look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/reference/entities/systemuser - I don't see delete action described.

Also, if I run api/data/v9.1/systemusers(11111111-1111-1111-111-111111111111) - PATCH works fine and changes user properties, but if I use DELETE, it says:

```
The 'Delete' method does not support entities of type 'systemuser'.
```

Is there a way to delete systemuser via API?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind this is that user record is so important that D365 disallows anybody to delete them. And this approach has reasons. For example what would be with audit records, modified by or created by lookups, etc.

The most sensible substitute of delete would be to reassign all records from user, remove all roles and disable user (set isdisabled).

If you are using on-premise and brave enough, you can delete it directly from DB. But I wouldn't ever do it.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. That makes sense. I'm not familiar with D365, however need to develop some functionality to work with it. So good to know. Thanks!